# CodeIgniter Change $db['xxx']['database']

Tags: php, codeigniter

have 1 mysql db, and 5 sql dbs.

Can I have this in config/database.php

```
$db['one']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['one']['username'] = 'myuser';
$db['one']['password'] = 'mypass';
$db['one']['database'] = 'dbONE';
$db['one']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['one']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['one']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['one']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['one']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['one']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache/';
$db['one']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['one']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['one']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['one']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['one']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost7';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbMySql';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache/';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

And want to change the value of $db[‘one’][‘database’] FROM dbONE to dbTWO on fly
is it possible or I must to write ALL DB configuration on config/database.php

Thanks in advance

I try this:

```
Case "dbONE":
    $db['one']['database'] = 'dbONE';
    $this->db_one = $this->load->database('one',TRUE);                
    $d=$this->invoice_model->invo('001');
    break;

  case "dbTWO":
    $db['one']['database'] = 'dbTWO';
    $this->db_one = $this->load->database('one',TRUE);   
    $d=$this->invoice_model->invo('001');
    break;
```

And always return the value from the db defined at databases.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you try:

```
$db['one']['database'] = 'dbTWO';
$this->load->database($db);
```